# Restrict 'Open Quickly's scope to currently open project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript, hotkeys

CMD+Shift+O ( ⌘⇧O ) brings up the 'Open Quickly' feature of Xcode. Much like CMD+T in Textmate & Sublime Text 2. Its scope of search seems to include system headers outside of my project.

Is there a way to restrict this scope to the currently open project? I can't find anything in Xcode preferences. This feature would be much more useful if this were possible.

[image: Open Quickly]

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  That is, tagging this question with `xcode`, `open` and `quickly` does not mean you are talking about the "Open Quickly" dialog in XCode.

Comment: I see, indeed, with the assumption I had, common words like open, quick, etc would be heavily populated and noisy then. Thanks, will keep this in mind while tagging next time :)

Comment: *"The search is case insensitive, and its scope is limited to the current project and the active SDK."*
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/opening_file_by_filename.html

The docs page doesn't say anything about restricting search scope, so it probably isn't possible.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra, In order to search inside the current project for files, go the project navigator on the left side of Xcode and at bottom search field, start typing the file name. It will filter the files based on the searched keyword and you can open the desired file once it is filtered. So it pretty much does the same feature.

Comment: To me this looks like a bug. In one of my project, it clearly searches only the current scope. In another one, I get the same result as you. Maybe this happens when you use a library that works for both iOS and Mac OS X.

Comment: Though it's a really old question, but has any one found a way to do it? The solutions mentioned below doesn't really satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Quick open lost its value to me. What you can do until the bug is fixed / scope can be specified:

Use: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Then type the file you want to 'Quick open'. This is restricted to the files in the project Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the scope is based on which navigator is currently chosen.  When I start getting weird results, I go select the project navigator, then try again and get the results I expected.